# What is the race condition in this code?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

The following is my implementation of `SleepConditionVariableCS`, `WakeAllConditionVariable`, and the thread creation functions. The problem is that sometimes when I try to create a thread the creating thread gets stuck on `WaitForSingleObject( cv->mut, INFINITE );` in `SleepConditionVariableCS`. I cant figure out what the race condition here is.

```
typedef struct
{
  int waiters_count;
  HANDLE sema_;
  HANDLE mut;
} CONDITION_VARIABLE;

void SleepConditionVariableCS(CONDITION_VARIABLE *cv, CRITICAL_SECTION *cs, int32_t dwMilliseconds){
    WaitForSingleObject( cv->mut, INFINITE ); //Acuire object lock

    cv->waiters_count++;
    LeaveCriticalSection (cs);
    if (SignalObjectAndWait(cv->mut, cv->sema_, dwMilliseconds, FALSE) == WAIT_TIMEOUT){ //SignalObjectAndWait releases the lock
        cv->waiters_count--;
    }
    EnterCriticalSection(cs);
}

void WakeAllConditionVariable(CONDITION_VARIABLE *cv){
    WaitForSingleObject( cv->mut, INFINITE );

    while (cv->waiters_count > 0){
        cv->waiters_count = cv->waiters_count - 1;
        ReleaseSemaphore (cv->sema_, 1, 0);
    }
    ReleaseMutex(cv->mut);
}

void KernelThread_CreationWait(void *kthread){
    KernelThread *thread =  (KernelThread *) kthread;

    EnterCriticalSection(thread->lock);
    thread->state = Thread_CREATED;

    WakeAllConditionVariable(thread->condition_variable);

    LeaveCriticalSection(thread->lock);
    KernelThread_main(kthread);
}

KernelThread* createKernelThread(){
    EventHandler_getHandler();

    unsigned long threadid;
    int t;
    void *hand;

    KernelThread *thread = KernelThread_malloc();
    EnterCriticalSection(thread->lock);
    thread->state = Thread_WAITINGFORCREATION;
    hand = CreateThread(NULL,
            0, // security, stack size
            (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&KernelThread_CreationWait, // start
            (void *)thread,
            0,
            &threadid); // param, creation flags, id
    if (hand == NULL){
        printf("ERROR: return handle from CreateThread() is NULL\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    thread->thread = hand;
    thread->thread_id = threadid;

    SleepConditionVariableCS(thread->condition_variable,thread->lock,INFINITE);
    LeaveCriticalSection(thread->lock);

    return thread;
}

void InitializeConditionVariable (CONDITION_VARIABLE *cv){
    cv->waiters_count = 0;
    cv->sema_ = CreateSemaphore (NULL,       // no security
                                0,          // initially 0
                                0x7fffffff, // max count
                                NULL);      // unnamed
    cv->mut = CreateMutex(
          NULL,              // default security attributes
          FALSE,             // initially not owned
          NULL);             // unnamed mutex
}
```

Comment: in ```SleepConditionVariableCS``` you call ```LeaveCriticalSection``` first and then ```EnterCriticalSection``` second. smells

Comment: @user931794 I know, but I acquired a different lock (`cv->mut`) to cover the gap. that was necessary because I cant simultaneously sleep and unlock a `CRITICAL_SECTION`. If you know specifically where the error is though, that would be very helpful.

Comment: probably a daft question but where does `thread->condition_variable` get initialised?

Comment: @simonc in `KernelThread_malloc()`

Comment: How does the mut get initialized?

Comment: @Fred added the init code

Comment: Just to be sure, thread->lock is a pointer to a CRITICAL_SECTION, right? And InitializeConditionVariable is called by KernelThread_malloc?

Comment: @Fred yessir, thats correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following very detailed analysis of the gotchas when trying to implement pthread-style condition variables using win32 apis. http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/win32-cv-1.html.  (Section 3.4, in particular).

In your code I see only one problem at the moment.  In `SleepConditionVariableCS()`:

```
    LeaveCriticalSection (cs);
    if (SignalObjectAndWait(cv->mut, cv->sema_, dwMilliseconds, FALSE) == WAIT_TIMEOUT){ //SignalObjectAndWait releases the lock
        // RIGHT HERE YOU HAVE NOT ACQUIRED cv->mut
        cv->waiters_count--; // SO THIS IS A DATA RACE (with the cv->waiters_count uses in WakeAllConditionVariable()
    }
```

Comment: Thats a good point, but do you know of how to rectify this without throwing it all out and copying a solution from the link? Would entering the lock before the decrement (with a nonzero check) work?

Comment: That would take care of the data race.  But then you run into other (less likely and more subtle) problems.  For example, you time out, but before you acquire cv->mut some other thread in SleepConditionVariableCS() might get cv->mut first and increment cv->waiters_count.  I can't quite wrap my head around that case, but I think it's not good.

Comment: Now that I think about it, this cant be the error because sleep is called with `INFINITE` therefore the return value will never be `WAIT_TIMEOUT`.

Comment: Ah, I see that now.  (I didn't notice the third argument to SleepConditionVariableCS() because it scrolled off to the right of the code box!)

Comment: Do you create any windows or call CoInitialize?  Threads that do either of those are not allowed to call WaitForSingleObject() with INFINITE timeout.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686293(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: thats only if you call those functions in the same thread during the span of the lock, which clearly isnt happening here.

Comment: That's not what the msdn article says.  "If a thread creates any windows, it must process messages... A thread that uses a wait function with no time-out interval may cause the system to become deadlocked."  It's not while you are calling those functions, it is whenever _the system_ decides to send your window an async message.  It's easy enough to check: change your calls to WaitForSingleObject(..., INFINITE) to a finite timeout, and wrap them in a while loop that checks the exit condition and spits something out if they timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I see no logic flaws that really stand out to me.

However...

Do you initialize CONDITION_VARIABLE to a known state before using it?

You do not check the return from a few of the system calls which could be returning an error that you'll never see.  `WaitForSingleObject` and `EnterCriticalSection` *can* fail or be given a bad handle.

Do you always lock `thread->lock` and keep it locked while dealing with the condition variables?  I see 2 different pieces of code with a reference to `thread->lock`.

Do you lock/unlock your critical sections and sems in the same order every time?

Comment: I understand that those are the best practices, but the code i've given itself is causing the race condition: the `createKernelThread` function blocks waiting for the already past `WakeAllConditionVariable` signal. In that code, you can see that the thread lock is acquired and not released until done. I am working on adding some more checking, but after checking `EnterCriticalSection` is void.

Comment: Nope, just got the race condition again with error checking added, no errors were reported on either `WaitForSingleObject`.